# How to use AngularJS UI Router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to use AngularJS UI Router to load view1 and view2, but they're being not loading into the index.html page. Can you please help?

[This is the link to whole project in Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YtchFtrg5PZXfM0wPwuM)

Also below, is the index.html page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Routing</title>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/angular2.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="ui-router@*" data-semver="1.0.0-alpha.5" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.0-alpha.5/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <a ui-sref="view1">view1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ui-sref="view2">view2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ui-sref="index">Home</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>Below you should see the partial view :) ... </div>
  <div ng-view="">
    <p>ng-view should be loading data from about.html right here but it's not working</p>
  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>

  <script src="controllers.js"></script> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have wrong markup. Use ui-view instead of ng-view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `ui-view` instead of `ng-view`(angular `ngRoute` routing api use this)

Comment: Thank you very much. That has helped me a lot!

Comment: @Maz glad to know that it helped, Thanks :-)